# RPi 4 second HDMI port does not seem to support CEC

Tags: pi-4, cec-client

When using the cec-utils on a Pi-4 with 2 HDMI devices connected, the one connected to HDMI1 does not respond to commands or show up in a scan.

Running cec-client -l only shows 1 device. Is there something I am missing or is there now way to control both devices using CEC?

Comment: What happens when you swap the cables? Can you connect to the same device, or to a different device on the same port?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` on your `/boot/config.txt` also only HDMI 1 works with `cec-utils`